# Kubernetes run command details

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl

I am learning Kubernetes. I have a question related to the K8s run command.

Command: `kubectl run testpod --image=nginx:alpine`

As per K8s documentation., run command creates a deployment or job to manage the containers.

Question: When I run the above commands, I can not see any new deployment. Why? Is it creating only pod?

Question: I am using Docker desktop. When I run above command, it is showing two different instances in docker desktop. Why two different instances?

[image]

Question: If I delete any instance from Docker desktop, a new instance is automatically generated. Why? I knew about deployment like if deployment behind of pod and that pod is down or deleted, deployment will automatically create a new pod. But, I cannot any deployment there.

Comment: did you try `kubectl get deployment --all-namespaces` ?

Comment: Yes, I knew this command and already cross-checked it. This command is showing only 1 deployment i.e.'kube-system'

Comment: what about `replicaset`?

Comment: Can you check all the resources using the command `kubectl get po,rs,rc,deploy`. If possible attach the output of this. (May be at least the ones which have the name `testpod`.) We can see if any ReplicationSet or ReplicationController or Deployment is available in your cluster.

Comment: Can you check what is the `kind` displayed in the yaml, when you run the command `kubectl run testpod --image=nginx:alpine --dry-run -o yaml`.
If possible attach this output as well.

Answer (score 0):

From this [documentation](https://jamesdefabia.github.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_run/)

Kubectl run command is used to Create and run a particular image, possibly replicated and also Creates a deployment or job to manage the created container(s).
But creating a instance or creating a deployment or creating the job depends on the usage of the command for suppose :

`kubectl run nginx --image=nginx` ---> Start a single instance of nginx.

`kubectl run nginx --image=nginx --replicas=5` ---> Start a replicated instance of nginx.

`kubectl run nginx --image=nginx --overrides='{ "apiVersion": "v1", "spec": { ... } }'` ---> Start a single instance of nginx, but overload the spec of the deployment with a partial set of values parsed from JSON.

--restart flag can also be used :

--restart="Always": The restart policy for this Pod.  Legal values [Always, OnFailure, Never].  **If set to 'Always' a deployment is created for this pod, if set to OnFailure or Never, a job is created for this pod** and --replicas must be 1.  Default 'Always'

For more details on deployment refer to this [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/).